# Absolute continuity of probabilities on Polish spaces and open sets.

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

On a polish space  $\mathcal{X}$ i consider two Borel probabilities $P$ and $Q$ such that for any open set $E$ of $\mathcal{X}$ we have : $P(E) =0$ implies $Q(E)=0$. Does this imply that $Q$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$ that is, that for any Borel set $E$ of $\mathcal{X}$ we have $P(E)=0$ implies $Q(E)=0$ ?

Comment: No: If $P$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, then $P(E) > 0$ for every open set $E$, and every probability measure $Q$ on $[0,1]$ vacuously satisfies your assumption.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your answer, how does this prove that the claim is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition means precisely that the **support** of the measure $Q$ (the minimal closed set of full measure) is contained in the support of the measure $P$. Obviously it has nothing to do with absolute continuity.

Comment: Why is this obvious ? Do you have any counter exemple ?

Comment: There is a lot of pairwise singular measures with the same support. For instance, look at the distribution of the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k/2^k \;,
$$
where $x_k$ are independent and take values 1 with probability $p$ and 0 with probability $1−p$. The resulting measures $m_p$ are pairwise singular (as it follows, for instance, from the law of large numbers) and have the same support $[0,1]$ (for $p=1/2$ this is the Lebesgue measure).